# Task Scheduler does not start Powershell Job

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, windows-task-scheduler

There are three Jobs set up on the server. All three starting within 10 minutes at 5 minute intervals (8:50, 8:55, 9:00).

The scheduled Jobs each start a .bat-File which is starting a PowerShell Script.

While the last Job runs properly the other two Jobs do not even start when run by Task Scheduler. Triggering the Jobs manually is no problem. The Jobs used to run without problems in the past. Now for some days the described problem occur.

The 3 Jobs are configured exactly the same in Task Scheduler. Even the initial .bat File is the same.

Here a few Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

One hint I found is in the Application Event Viewer. The event's timestamp are matching to the starting points of first two scheduled Jobs.
[image]

**EDIT 1:**
This is the error details from the Application Event:

> Fault bucket , type 0 Event Name: PowerShell Response: Not available
> Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1: powershell.exe P2: 10.0.14393.4402 P3:
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COM P4:
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COM P5:
> ent.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc P6:
> System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative P7: Pipeli..ution Thread P8:
> P9:  P10:
>
> Attached files:
>
> These files may be available here:
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\Critical_powershell.exe_2381577626a3dc129427bb0808e542014c3abe_00000000_054ed9bf
>
> Analysis symbol:  Rechecking for solution: 0 Report Id:
> d6944bbc-b3b8-11eb-a95f-005056933685 Report Status: 2 Hashed bucket:

**EDIT 2:**
this is the content of the .bat file which starts the PS Script:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET PsScriptDirectory=%~dp0
SET PsScriptPath=%PsScriptDirectory%unknown.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%PsScriptPath%""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

Comment: Can you look at the Problem Signature in the event?
Search Powershell fault bucket there is some results too.

Comment: I have added the error details. What could this indicate?

Comment: Does any of your script use System.Threading or WaitOne() ? The `P7:` data isn't clear.
I don't know the content of your script but COM objects are not always thread-safe. Default PowerShell is single thread. But you said the content hasn't changed. May each independent script access a shared ressources ? If one script take longer than previously, access to the same object may cause issues on the other script.

Comment: Actually each script has access to a corresponding text-file, there is no interference. I posted the content of the .bat file.